# Is operator->() guaranteed to be available for a standard C++ container's iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, standards, language-design

```
#include <map>

int main()
{
    auto coll = std::map<int, int>{{1, 2}};
    auto pos  = coll.begin();

    (*pos).first;   // OK. Conforming to the C++ standard.
    pos->first;     // Does this conform to the C++ standard too?
}
```

According to [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator), an iterator object `pos` must guarantee `*pos` and `++pos` are valid expressions. However, the C++ standard doesn't require that `pos->first` must also be a valid expression.

**Is** `operator->()` **guaranteed to be available for a standard C++ container's iterator?**

Comment: Every standard container offers a stronger guarantee than `LegacyIterator`

Comment: "The overload of operator -> must either return a raw pointer, or return an object (by reference or by value) for which operator -> is in turn overloaded. " I found that in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Comment: `LegacyInputIterator` and derived requirements require the `->` operator.

Comment: @Carlos -- that link describes general requirements on overloads of `operator->`, but it does not address whether iterators are required to provide it.

Comment: @interjay, I got it. Thank you very much. see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator

Comment: @xmllmx: Answers go in the answer section, not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C++17 named iterator requirements for [InputIterator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/input.iterators#2), and therefore all derivations, does require that iterators provide `operator->`. However, the C++20 iterator *concepts* do not. Particular implementations may provide them, and the standard library containers follow the rules of both the C++17 requirements and C++20 concepts.

So if you have a template function that constrains itself against the C++20 iterator/range concepts, you are not allowed to use `->`. Of course, if you're in non-template code and you know what types you're being given, you can use the full interface available to you.

Note that C++17's OutputIterator requirements do *not* include `->`. So any standard library iterators that are pure OutputIterators (`ostream_iterator`, for example) does not necessarily provide it.

Answer (score 1):

If the standard says that iterator_traits::pointer and iterator_traits::reference are non-void types, than the standard guarantees that the iterator must have an operator->

> 23.3.2.3 Iterator traits [iterator.traits]
> 1 To implement algorithms only in terms of iterators, it is sometimes necessary to determine the iterator
> category that corresponds to a particular iterator type. Accordingly, it is required that if I is the type of an
> iterator, the type
> iterator_traits::iterator_category
> be defined as the iterator’s iterator category. In addition, the types
> iterator_traits::pointer
> iterator_traits::reference
> shall be defined as the iterator’s pointer and reference types; that is, for an iterator object a of class
> type, the same type as decltype(a.operator->()) and decltype(*a), respectively. The type iterator_-
> traits::pointer shall be void for an iterator of class type I that does not support operator->.
> Additionally, in the case of an output iterator, the types

Comment: Does that hold for `std::vector<bool>` too or are there exceptions? That [seems to fail in most compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/dbrE4KPor)